# Where is fabric8 console on Kops AWS gossip based kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8, kops

I have a working Kubernetes gossip-based cluster deployed on AWS using Kops.
On this I deployed  fabric8.
Command "gofabric8 validate" indicates success.

Now how can I access the fabric8 console?

Note: Because its a gossip based cluster I dont need a domain.
So I installed using: "gofabric8 deploy -y --pv=false" (Did not specify any domain). 
I installed from same machine which I used to create my kops 1 master 2 node cluster on AWS.
Please do let me know if I must do anything different if needed.

Raster

Answer (score 0):

To access fabric8 console, you simply have to run following command,

```
gofabric8 console
```

For more information, goto `gofabric8` [README](https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8)